# How to update a value in a column in a datatable which is in a foreachloop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, foreach, dataset

I want to update all columns one by one in a datatable using a foreach loop. The code below is what I have so far. But it does not seem to work. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
 foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows) 
 {
     Double i;
     Double j = Convert.ToDouble(row["x"]);
     int y = 1;

     int aan = (int)row["year"];

         if(y == aan) 
         {
            i = j + 2;
         }

     row["x"]=i;
     row.EndEdit();
     myTable.AcceptChanges();

  }
```

Comment: use a For Loop MDSN... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

Comment: This code can't compile. You are missing an opening brace. Without it's impossible to tell what's wrong

Comment: You want to update each `COLUMN` or each `ROW`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code works fine for me, except for a few tweaks. The code is given below:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows) 
        {
             Double i = 0;
             Double j = Convert.ToDouble(row["x"]);
             int y = 1;

             int aan = Convert.ToInt32(row["year"]);

                 if(y == aan) 
                 {
                    i = j + 2;
                 }

             row["x"]=i;
             row.EndEdit();
             myTable.AcceptChanges();

        }
```

Are you facing any specific issues?

Comment: Thanks I sorted it out I had it inside a try and catch. That is why it was not working