# Unable to update value in myDataTable.Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

This should be a simple operation, but my field is not being updated.  I'm likely doing something wrong that will hopefully be obvious to someone here.

All I want is to strip the time off the datetime before binding to my GridView.  My query runs and populates a DataSet.  Then we do this:

```
    try
    {
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
        // strip time off WEDate
        foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(row["WEDate"].ToString());
            string myNewValue = dt.ToShortDateString();
            row["WEDate"] = myNewValue;
        }
        BudgetGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
        BudgetGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

No exceptions throw, page loads, and the time is still on the WEDate.  I stuck the "string myNewValue" in there just to debug through and confirm it was actually stripped off.  It is.  So the offending line seems to be:

```
row["WEDATE"] = myNewValue
```

That update is not happening.

Any clues?

UPDATE: Based on this posting, I made the update below:
[How to update a value in a column in a datatable which is in a foreachloop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750814/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-column-in-a-datatable-which-is-in-a-foreachloop)

```
            row.EndEdit();
            myDataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Still no joy.  The field is not being updated.

Comment: is there a date in myNewValue?

Comment: Why don't you do that in the frontend, for example via [`BoundField.DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) ? `DataFormatString="{0:d}"`

Comment: @Sam: Yes, there is a date there.  I put that line in so I could step through with the debugger and see if the time was actually being stripped off.  It is.

Comment: @Tim:  I'm open to doing this on the front end if I knew how that would work.  If my aspx looks like this: <asp:Label ID="WEDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WEDate") %>'></asp:Label>
 where does the DataFormatString go?

Comment: Btw, have you used the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: If the object's type is datetime and you wanna ensure some sort of specific format, the way to go is returning a string representation of that date (with the desired format), but not returning the date itself. (If you wanna resolve this with your backend code of course).

Comment: @Tim When I step through it with the debugger, the time is stripped off the date so myNewValue = "04/01/2013" for example.  The next line should update the datarow row["WEDate"] field, but that's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do that in the frontend, for example via [`BoundField.DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)?

```
DataFormatString="{0:d}"
```

> I'm open to doing this on the front end if I knew how that would work.
>   If my aspx looks like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="WEDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WEDate") %>'></asp:Label>
```

> where does the DataFormatString go?

If you use a `TemplateField` you could use the overload of `Eval`:

```
Text='<%# Eval("WEDate", "0:d") %>'
```

---

**Edit**: Your code above already shows that `WEDate` is a string that you need to parse to a `DateTime` first, that's why above approach does only show a literal `0:d`.

I would use codebehind, especially `RowDataBound` of the `GridView`:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        Label WEDateLabel = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("WEDateLabel");
        DateTime weDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("WEDate"));
        WEDateLabel.Text = weDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That server tag is placing a literal "0:d" in the field. What would cause that?

Comment: Is `WEDate` really a `DateTime` or a string that looks like a `DateTime`? Try this instead: `<%# string.Format("{0:d}", Eval("WEDate"))%>`. **Edit** forget my question. `WEDate` is a string not a date, that's the reason for the litaral.

Comment: @DJGray: Edited my answer to provide the approach that i would use.

Comment: Shazzam!!  That's what the issue was.  I was manipulating a string rather than an actual DT.  Thanks Tim!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could do this when you bind you label

```
Text='<%# Bind("WEDate", "{0:d}")%>'
```

Comment: That server tag is placing a literal "0:d" in the field. What would cause that?

Comment: Hi that literal is to format your datetime column in short date it works like stringformat in code behind but this is in HTML